# prove that $Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (X_k - \mu_k)$ converges a.s.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, self-learning

Let  $\{ X_n, n\in N\}$ be a sequence of rrvs in $L_2 (\omega, A, P)$ with $\mu_n = E(X_n)$ and $\sigma_n^2 = \sigma^2 (X_n) $

Part - 1:

suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_n^2 < \infty$. Prove that $\{ X_n - \mu_n, n\ge 1\}$ converges to 0 a.s.

Part - 2:

suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} n^4 \sigma_n^2 < \infty$. Then prove that $Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^ n (X_k - \mu_k)$ converges a.s.

---

My solution for part - 1:

By Cheybshev inequality,

$P(|X_n - \mu_n|>e ) \le \sigma^2_n / e^2$ for small enough e>0

Define $A_n = \{ w: |X_n - \mu_n|>e \}$ such that

$P(A_n) = P(|X_n - \mu_n|>e ) \le \sigma^2_n / e^2$

$\sum P(A_n) \le \sum \sigma^2_n / e^2 < \infty$

By Borel Contelli lemma

if $\sum P(A_n) < \infty$, $P(limsup A_n) = P( U \{ X_n- \mu_n\})=0$

Then, $\{ X_n- \mu_n\} \to 0$ a.s.

So far, I hope it is true. (since I am not sure) And I am stack with doing part 2.How can I deal with the part - 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the first part correctly.

$E|X_k-\mu_k| \leq \sqrt {E(X_k-\mu_k)^{2}}=\sigma_k$. Note that $\sum \sigma_k =\sum (k^{2}\sigma_k) (\frac  1{k^{2}})$. By C-S/Holder's inequlity we see that $E\sum |X_k-\mu_k|=\sum \sigma_k <\infty$. Hence $\sum (X_k-\mu_k)$ converges absoluetly with probaility $1$.

Comment: In this case, I cannot see the part after " Hence the sum converges absolutely with probability 1." How do we get this? And also, why don't we use $\sum n^4 \sigma^2 < \infty $?

Comment: by the way, there was a typo in the question. I corrected it

Comment: I did use the hypothesis after applying C-S inequality. $EY<\infty$ implies $Y<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: I see now thanks a lot :)